# UIActivityViewController Size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use UIActivityController in my app. Unfortunately the size of the modal is far too large. 
On the left, the modal I want, on the right, the modal I have :

[image]

And here is the code I use to display the modal when I click on the Share button :

```
NSString *textToShare = @"Hello !";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

// Email subject
[activityVC setValue:@"Hello !" forKey:@"subject"];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing something crucial - your whole app is scaled up. Notice the size of your status bar. You are missing the proper launch images. Better yet, use a launch screen instead of launch images.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I never noticed this. Thank you ! So now, how can I replace launch images by launch screen ?

Comment: I found, now I have to design again all my layout \o/. Thanks again.

Comment: I have now another problem, when I specify the Launch Screen File, I have a black launch screen :(.

Answer (score -1):

You're doing nothing wrong, you're just using a differently sized device! Try running in the simulator using iPhone 6 or iPhone 6S and I bet you'll see exactly what you want on the left. Looks like you're just running it on a smaller device than what you want.