# iOS share sheet scale modification

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm writing my app on iOS 9.3.  However, my app's share sheet screen is bigger than the other app's share sheet screen.  Is there any way to modify the share sheet screen to the iPhone original icons size?

Following are my code:

```
- (IBAction)onShareButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {

NSString *string = @"Upload Chart";
UIImage *uploadImage = [self.selectedController performSelector:@selector(getUploadImage)];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, uploadImage] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

As the comment below, I found that `getUploadImage` is only getting the part of the screen.

if I modify the code as follow, the share sheet would be only "more more" instead.  However, the size of the share icon is the same as the origin.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityVC applicationActivities:nil];
```

Because the `activityVC` is empty.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430005/uiactivityviewcontroller-size and my comments below the question.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll manage my question.